# Best way to setup a webhook for dialogflow fulfilment?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using the inline code editor with dialogflow. But i want to use an external webhook I just wasn't sure the best way to do this. I've got some experience with firebase and firebase functions - so if I wanted to create a firebase project i'd just run firebase init, etc. Can the url for the webhook be the firebase functions url?

In addition there are is the action on google github page https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs where there are examples of writing conversational code for dialogflow using a dialogflow instance but the syntax for this is different to the syntax used in fulfilment. Just wondering the differences between writing code for actions on google versus dialogflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions-on-Google and Dialogflow Fulfillment are different things. You can use AOG SDK if you want your agent to be integrated only with Google Assistant. Dialogflow Fulfillment SDK will help in case you are integrating it with multiple platforms.

You can use Firebase Functions for your external webhook and the webhook URL can be the firebase functions URL. We are hosting one of our Dialogflow agent's webhook on firebase functions, so you can go with that too.

Comment: Thx. So got webhook working. Just had a quick ques the url is http://....cloudfunctions.net/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment and that triggers exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment. So all my code is basically in the one function. Is that how your project is setup?

Comment: Yes. I have kept all my intent handler files in a separate folder and create a map of intent name and handler in the main function and then passed the map to the agent.handleRequest() function.